# Mathematical difference between solitons and traveling waves for a non-linear dispersive PDE

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, physics

I see many mathematicians conflating the definitions of traveling waves and solitons, and I am unable to understand, from a mathematical point of view, the differences between these two types of solutions for a nonlinear dispersive PDE. All I know is the following:

Consider for example a nonlinear dispersive PDE which is [completely integrable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrable_system), i.e. has infinite conservation laws, ( I think the property of complete integrability will not probably add something to the question)

- The **traveling waves** are solutions of the form $u_0(x+ct)$ where $u_0$ is the initial data and $c\in\mathbb{R}$.
- The **Solitons** are subset of the traveling waves, that remain with the same shape even after colliding with another soliton. The phenomena of solitons appear after a cancelation between the dispersive effects and the nonlinearity of the equation.

So here are my questions:

1. How do we know if a nonlinear PDE has solitons as solutions, knowing that it has traveling wave solutions ? On other words, how do we prove mathematically that a traveling wave is a soliton (without using simulation).
2. For example, solutions of the form $u(t,x)=e^{i(x-t)}$ or $u(t,x)=\frac{1}{1-\frac12 e^{i(x-ct)}}$, $x\in \mathbb{T}:=\mathbb{R}/(2\pi\mathbb{Z}),$ can be considered as solitons?
3. Does a traveling wave that is almost periodic solution, *i.e. the set $\{u(\cdot+\tau), \tau\in \mathbb{R}\}$ is relatively compact*, can lead to the fact that it is a soliton ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A necessary requirement for a traveling wave $u(x,t)=f(x-ct)$ to be a "solitary wave" or "soliton"  is that the two limits $\lim_{s\rightarrow\pm\infty}f(s)=\alpha_\pm$ exist. This is the condition of *shape invariance* and *localisation*. The stability under collision may or may not be added as extra condition, but in much of the literature any shape-invariant localised wave is called a soliton. One further distinguishes homoclinic and heteroclinic solutions, depending on whether $\alpha_+$ is equal to $\alpha_-$ or not.

In response to Q2, the waves $u(t,x)=e^{i(x-t)}$ or $u(t,x)=\frac{1}{1-\frac12 e^{i(x-ct)}}$ are no solitons, because they are not localised.

Concerning Q1, without the "stability upon collision" condition, one way to identify solitonic solutions of a second order wave equation $f''(s)=F[f(s)]$ is to plot the flow lines in the *f-g* plane of the two coupled equations $f'(s)=g(s)$, $g'(s)=F[f(s)]$. [Homoclinic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homoclinic_orbit) or [heteroclinic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heteroclinic_orbit) orbits then correspond to solitonic solutions.

Comment: Thank you ! Even if we are in a periodic domain, we should look at what happens when $s\to\pm \infty$ and not the limit when $s$ tends to the boundary of the domain? Because I wonder if this limit means that we are looking at the behavior of the initial data in long time behavior, or rather what happens when we approach the edge of our space.

Comment: I think it is what happen with long time behavior, but I want to be sure ;-)

Comment: if you have periodic boundary conditions you would want the spatial extent of the soliton to be smaller than the size of the domain, so that you can see if it is spatially localized or not; if it extends over the entire domain the notion of a "solitary wave" is no longer applicable.

Comment: So, for the two examples in Q2, since we have $\lim_{x\to2\pi}\mathrm{e}^{ix}=1\neq 0,$ then it is not localized ? And the same goes for the second example. In other words, we need to have the support of $f$ strictly included in a box of the periodic domain?

Comment: yes, that is what we understand as a "localized" wave.

Comment: Thank you ! I have one additional question. 
In general, many PDEs are known to be locally well-posed in Sobolev spaces $H^s(\mathbb{R})$ with $s$ not so much negative. Thus, for example, if we exhibit a traveling wave that belongs to $L^2(\mathbb{R}),$  then of course, we have $\lim_{s\to\pm}f(s)=0$. This means that every traveling wave in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ is a homoclinic soliton ? (The spatial variable here is $x\in\mathbb{R}$).

Comment: yes, any square integrable solution $f(x-ct)$ in $\mathbb{R}$ is a localised wave, but you will not find it in a linear PDE.

Answer (score 3):

Terry Tao's expository article [Why are solitons stable](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0802.2408.pdf) should clarify some of your questions. See in particular the footnote on page 8.

Consider for example the focusing nonlinear Schrödinger (NLS) equation $i\partial_t u+\Delta u+u|u|^{p-1}=0$ where $u:\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}^d\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$. A stationary state can be defined to be an time-independent solution $u(t,x)=Q(x)$, where $Q$ has to solve $\Delta Q+Q|Q|^{p-1}=0$. A soliton is defined to be a time-periodic solution $u(t,x)=e^{it}Q(x)$, where $Q$ has to solve $\Delta Q-Q+Q|Q|^{p-1}=0$.

Existence of solitons is inferred by variational methods: if you try to minimize the quantity $\| v\|_{H^1(\mathbb{R}^d)}$ over the set $$\{v\in H^1_{\text{radial}}(\mathbb{R}^d),\ \| v\|_{L^{p+1}(\mathbb{R}^d)} =1 \}$$
you can prove (with some work, see for example Terry Tao's [book](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/books/nonlinear-dispersive-equations-local-and-global-analysis/) on nonlinear dispersive equations) that the minimizer exists and, up to rescaling and (phase) shift, solves precisely the soliton equation $\Delta Q-Q+Q|Q|^{p-1}=0$.

If your initial data (to focusing NLS) is close to that of the soliton, i.e. $\|u_0-Q\|<\varepsilon$, in a certain range of parameters (for example if $p<1+\frac{4}{d}$) you can show that the solution $u$ stays close (in the $H^1$ norm) to a modulated ((phase) shifted) version of the soliton. To do this, you can use the concentration-compactness lemma which describes the ways in which the embedding $H^1\subset L^p$ can fail to be compact.